# Display pdf byte[] or base64 string to WPF web browser without saving it in a local file

Tags: c#, wpf, base64, webbrowser-control

I have a .net web api that get a `byte[]` from a pdf file, convert it into a base64 `string` and send it to a frontend, in my case a WPF application.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use directly the base64 `string` or a `byte[]` to display my pdf into WPF web browser without saving it in a local temp directory.

I have also tried to convert my `byte[]` into a `MemoryStream` and use it as a param in `WebBrowser.NavigateToStream()` but the result was a black page.

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(mypdfstring);
FileStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

```
 <WebBrowser utils:WebBrowserUtility.BindableStreamSource="{Binding FileStream}"/>
```

```
 public static void BindableStreamSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject o,     DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            WebBrowser browser = o as WebBrowser;
            if(browser != null)
            {
                Stream stream = e.NewValue as Stream;

                if (stream is null)
                    return;
                stream.Position = 0;
                browser.NavigateToStream(stream);
            }
        }
```

### Edit

I have setted to 0 the position of the stream and now the web browser shows my pdf file in this form

```
%PDF-1.7 1 0 obj <> stream ÿØÿàJFIF,,ÿÛC     ÿÛC   ÿÀ ° °"ÿÄ ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢
```

is only a small portion

Comment: You might want to check the `Length` of the stream instead. If it is 0, then the stream is empty. Try also to set the `stream.Position = 0` before calling `NavigateToStream()`.

Comment: See the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostream?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks): *If the stream parameter is not in a valid HTML format, it will be displayed as plain text.*

Comment: A document format library can decode and display the PDF. As an example, if you pass the `MemoryStream` to the [RasterCodecs.Load](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/co/rastercodecs-load(stream).html) method from the LEADTOOLS SDK, the PDF will be loaded in a [RasterImage](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/l/rasterimage.html) object that you can use in your WPF frontend. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)